# Is it possible to search Twitter Users by number of followers?

Tags: twitter

I would like to find public users on Twitter that have 0 followers. I was thinking of using https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search, but this doesn't have a way to filter by number of followers. Are there any simple alternatives? (Otherwise, I might have to resort to using a graph/search based approach starting from a random point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bird SQL by Perplexity AI allows you to do this simply: https://www.perplexity.ai/sql

Query: `Users with 0 followers, and 0 following, with at least 5 tweets`

```sql
SELECT user_url, full_name, followers_count, following_count, tweet_count
FROM users
WHERE (followers_count = 0)
  AND (following_count = 0)
  AND (tweet_count >= 5)
ORDER BY tweet_count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: and how to use this query on Twitter

Comment: is bird over? don't see it on perplexity anymore

Comment: @mylord Seems like it, unfortunately. I'm not aware of any alternatives at the moment that are as simple to use

Answer (score 2):

Well you didn't specify what library you are using to interact with the Twitter API. But regardless of which technology you're using, the underlying concept is the same. I will use tweepy library in python for my example.

Start by getting the public users using [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search). The return type is a list of user objects. The user object has several attributes which you can learn about [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object). For now we are interested in the ***followers_count*** attribute. Simply loop through the objects returned and check where the value of this attribute is 0.

Here's how the implementation would look like in python using tweepy library;

```
search_query = 'your search query here'
get_users = api.search_users(q = search_query)#Returns a list of user objects
for users in get_users:
    if users.followers_count ==0:
        #Do stuff if the user has 0 followers
```

Comment: The library in this case is irrelevant, as I'm wondering about the capabilities of the API itself. As for your suggested approach, it requires a search query, but this unnecessarily narrows down result set. I would like to get all users who satisfy the condition followers_count == 0

Comment: This is the only method for doing it - there is no built-in API feature that enables search by number of followers. You'd have to search on some other condition, and then filter by the number in your own code.